# Bi-directional data transfer through USB between an Android device and a PC (Mac or Windows)

Tags: android, usb

I am new to Android programming.
I need to transfer data bi-directionally over USB between an Android tablet and a PC (Mac or Windows).
The Android tablet will have Android 4.0 or newer.
Mac will have OS X Lion or newer and Windows will have Windows XP or newer.

After reading about Android's support for USB connectivity here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

I'm thinking if I get the Android tablet run in USB accessory mode and make the PC the host, bi-directional data transfer over USB can work.  Is that thinking correct or I'm way off here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey! ytw have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Vijju I ended up using "adb forward" command to establish a connection for bi-directional data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably ADB push/pull of files (assuming that's what you want to transfer). Your Windows-side application would have adb and AdbWinApi.dll as assets, and the OSX version would have the Mac OS ADB binary...
There are obvious downsides such as having to have Developer options enabled on the device, and possible interference from a pre-existing copy  of the Android SDK on the host machine (typically very unlikely, but possible!)

More advanced: Depending on the environment, you may even want to look into building your own version of ADB from source with unnecessary features omitted.